# form tag just one value pass instead of multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form_tag in form which contains two drop down boxes. When I submit the form both fields id isn't pass I dont know where did i do a wrong...

```
<%= form_tag '/daily_report' do -%>
<label>Search</label>
<%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "firstname",:selected => @s) %>
<%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, "id", "name",:selected => @s) %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: If you use the same name the values will be overwritten and you will get only one data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same name the values will be overwritten and you will get only one result. So change the name and make it different.

```
<%= select_tag "users", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "firstname",:selected => @s) %>
<%= select_tag "projects", options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, "id", "name",:selected => @s) %>
```

You can now access using the names, `:users` and `:projects`